# Makefile with share test problem directory

Tags: c, makefile

```
                      $Project
                         |
       ------------------+----------------+
       |                 |                |
      Method1          Method2          Test-Problems
```

I am working on a C-language project and I need to compare implementation of two methods applying them the same test problems. How should I write the makefile?

Now I have the files of tests-problems duplicate on each method's directory and I use the next simple makefile:

```
# Compiler.
SYS = Linux
CC = /usr/bin/gcc 

# FLAGS.
MPFRPATH=/usr/local/include/
FLAGS=-I$(MPFRPATH) -O2 -Wall -std=c99 -fno-common -mfma

#LIBFLAGS.
LIBPATH1=/usr/local/lib/
LIBFLAGS=-L$(LIBPATH1) 

OBJECTS = *.o

%.o: %.c 
   ${CC} -D MPFR_WANT_FLOAT128 -fPIC ${FLAGS} -c -I./  $<

fun: $(OBJECTS) 
   ${CC}  -shared -o libMethod1.so -fPIC $(OBJECTS) $(LIBFLAGS) -lmpfr -lgmp
```

Comment: 1) Welcome to Stack Overflow. 2) What are the test problems, and how do you use them? 3) That makefile has some shortcomings. 4) Do you intend to incorporate the test problems into the library?

Answer (score 0):

Make has `-C directory` and `-f Makefile` options. So, if you store your Makefile in your top directory you can invoke make from this top directory with:

```
make -C Method1 -f ../Makefile
```

And if you have differences between the two cases you can use make variables to handle them. For instance with a variable `M` with value `1` or `2`:

```
fun: $(OBJECTS)
    ${CC} -shared -o libMethod$(M).so ...
```

and:

```
make -C Method1 -f ../Makefile M=1
```

You could also test the current directory from inside the Makefile instead of passing the make variable on the command line:

```
M = $(patsubst Method%,%,$(notdir $(PWD)))
...
fun: $(OBJECTS)
    ${CC} -shared -o libMethod$(M).so ...
```

It has nothing to do with your question but there are some problems with your Makefile. You should consider using the standard make variables `CFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS` and `LDLIBS` instead of custom ones, and the automatic variables (`$@`, `$^`...). As make already knows how to compile source files, if you use the standard make variables you do not even need to write a rule yourself.

More important you should not use wildcards to get the list of object files: if they don't exist yet the list is empty. Always use wildcards on the source files as you are sure they exist already. And do not use non-file targets (`fun`) when a file target would do the job (`libMethod1.so`):

```
M        = $(patsubst Method%,%,$(notdir $(PWD)))
INCLUDE  = /usr/local/include .
CFLAGS   = $(addprefix -I,$(INCLUDE)) -O2 -Wall -std=c99 
CFLAGS   += -shared -fno-common -mfma -fPIC -DMPFR_WANT_FLOAT128
LIBPATH  = /usr/local/lib
LDFLAGS  = $(addprefix -L,$(LIBPATH))
LDLIBS   = -lmpfr -lgmp
SOURCES  = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS  = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES))

libMethod$(M).so: $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o$@ $^ $(LDIBS)
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I think I did not explain myself well. 
In test-problems directory I have problems.c file and when I try to compile/link the method1 I get this error:

Comment: gcc: error: ../ODEProblems/Problems.o: No such file or directory